# Phonon and image support

Tags: qt, image, pyqt, phonon

I'm trying to build a simple slideshow-like effect using Phonon with PyQt.  The "slideshow" will be made up of images and/or video, but the images should display for some fixed period of time.  When I queue up an image in a `MediaSource`, it is displayed for only a short moment.

Phonon appears to support images via the backend (at least on OS X with Quicktime), but I haven't found anything documented to indicate this.  The `Phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableMimeTypes()` function only returns audio and video formats; none of the formats I've successfully tested - JPEG, PNG - are listed.

I need to determine if a given `MediaSource` is an image or not, so I can tell the `MediaOjbect` to pause for some given period of time.  Of course I can make a big list of known image format extensions, and check the filename of the media - but this is kludgy.  How can I do this with Phonon?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related: [Enabling JPEG support for QImage in py2exe-compiled Python scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885906/enabling-jpeg-support-for-qimage-in-py2exe-compiled-python-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Phonon (from everything I've read) is designed for displaying individual audio/video files so I would guess if you want a slideshow you'd have to display images in the normal Qt way rather than using Phonon for them.