# pyqt jpeg support not working in bundled form

Tags: python, pyqt4, py2exe

To enable jpeg support in a PyQT application, you have to manually include the `qjpeg4.dll`.
It works fine when the dll and pyd file are not bundled together in the final exe. For example
with py2exe you can do the following :

```
DATA=[('imageformats',['C:\\Python26/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/plugins/imageformats/qjpeg4.dll'])]
setup(console=[{"script":"cycotic.py"}], 
    data_files = DATA,
    options={"py2exe":{
        "includes":["sip"],
        "excludes":MODULE_EXCLUDES,
        "bundle_files":3,
        "compressed":False,
        "xref":True}}, 
    zipfile=None)
```

However, if you do the same thing, and you bundle the dll in the exe (using `"bundle_files":1`), it fails with the following message :

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x3a16608) is not the object's thread (0x
2dddaf8).
Cannot move to target thread (0x2dddaf8)

QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x3a16608) is not the object's thread (0x
2dddaf8).
Cannot move to target thread (0x2dddaf8)

QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x3a16608) is not the object's thread (0x
2dddaf8).
Cannot move to target thread (0x2dddaf8)

QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
```

How can I bundle the application properly ?

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem, As I know, py2exe has provided the clue:
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyQt

It reads:
......so you'll need to copy the folder PyQt4\plugins\imageformats to \imageformats. ....... **This won't work with bundle_files on**.
...
***This will work with bundle_files as well, but you need to exclude the Qt DLLs from bundle (using the dll_excludes option) and add them to the directory with the executable through some other mechanism (such as data_files).***

following is my setup options, like this:

```
    zipfile=None,
    options = { "py2exe" :{
                           "compressed":1,
                           "includes": my_includes,                           
                           "packages": my_packages,
                           "optimize":2,
                           "bundle_files":1,
                           "dll_excludes":["QtCore4.dll","QtGui4.dll","QtNetwork4.dll"]
                           }}
```

So the dist folder consists these files (in my case):

- imageformats (folder, include qt plugin dll to deal with images)
- QtCore4.dll
- QtGui4.dll
- QtNetwork4.dll
- MyExeFile.exe
- w9xpopen.exe

that's all

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `pyqt4` as a package to force py2exe to include everything from PyQT in your build, like this:

```
options={"py2exe":{
        "includes":["sip"],
        "excludes":MODULE_EXCLUDES,
        "packages":["PyQt4"],
        "bundle_files":1,
        "compressed":False,
        "xref":True}}
```

Comment: Modified pyqt -> PyQt4 to have a valid package name, but it failed.
Apparently PyQt4 does not like to be include this way. It fails with :

error: compiling 'C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\port_v3\proxy_base.py'
 failed
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax (proxy_base.py, line 4)

Comment: That is a bug in proxy_base.py? add proxy_base to your Excludes and see if it builds