# pyside + py2exe, user loaded images do not appear

Tags: python, py2exe, pyside

I have an application written with pyside where a user can load an image, via either drag&drop or through a dialog box, and the image name and a thumbnail will show up in a QTreeWidget.  When I run normally (within Eclipse) everything works fine.  When I package the project with py2exe it no longer displays the image.  I assume it is because py2exe is not finding the image libraries used by pyside.  I do not know enough about pyside and py2exe to know if this is the actual issue.  After doing some searches I found a lot of information on people not able to display images that are apart of the application (icons) which I have already resolved (Edit - These were png files which is why they showed up after I bundled the images in the py2exe step).

I am using QPixMap to load the thumbnail image into a QIcon.  I then add the icon to a QTreeWidgetItem.

```
icon = QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(url),QIcon.Normal,QIcon.Off)
item = QTreeWidgetItem([...])
item.setIcon(0,icon)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming you are using probably a jpeg and not png. Png will work natively but jpeg requires an image plugin to be properly packaged into your exe

[Enabling JPEG support for QImage in py2exe-compiled Python scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885906/enabling-jpeg-support-for-qimage-in-py2exe-compiled-python-scripts)

Comment: Also, on Qt wiki: [Packaging PySide applications on Windows](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Packaging_PySide_applications_on_Windows)

Comment: This did it.  I think the reason I did not see it before was because this was for pyqt and not specifically pyside.  Glad that it works for both.  Thanks!

Comment: PySide and PyQt are both built against Qt. Pretty much all the information is applicable between them.

Comment: Right I was just trying to figure out why it did not come up in the search. :)