# Qt imageformats not supported even if plugins included

Tags: qt, jpeg, image-formats

Qt image formats (jpeg) not supported in my app (builded with Qt 5.12 MinGW) on other computers. plugins already added to {appDir}/imageformats. I also tried to load qjpeg.dll dynaically by QLibrary::load().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I could add it by `QtCore.QCoreApplication.addLibraryPath("dll-path")`

This code must be placed above the `QApplication` instance.

Please make sure the path name again.

And you add the code before making `QtGui.QApplication` instance.

If this answer is out the point, I will delete it.

Comment: "dll-path" is file folda name."plugin" in my case. Not directly .dll file.

Comment: C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats from the [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885906/enabling-jpeg-support-for-qimage-in-py2exe-compiled-python-scripts?rq=1] imageformats folda is

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved. The real problem comes from initializing a static variable of type QImage.